# Calling element from imported XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

My first xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="my.com/V1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:abc="my.com/V1.0.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

My new xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="my.com/V2.0.xsd"
           xmlns:abc="my.com/V2.0.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import 
namespace="my.com/V1.0.xsd" schemaLocation="V1.0.xsd"/>
```

I'm new to XSD thus my question may sound silly, but it would be great if someone can help me.

Now in V2.0.xsd, I want to call elements, complexTypes in V1.0.xsd, how can I do something likes this ? I though all elements will now in gathered under abc namespace, unfortunately, things didn't work as I hope.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import v1 elements in your v2 schema you have to qualify the reference to your v1 element or complexType in the v2 schema.

e.g.:
Given a v1 schema like that:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="my.com/V1.0.xsd"
xmlns:v1="my.com/V1.0.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="typeV1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="fromV1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

the v2 schema call the complex type like that:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="my.com/V2.0.xsd"
  xmlns:v2="my.com/V2.0.xsd"
  xmlns:v1="my.com/V1.0.xsd"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="my.com/V1.0.xsd" schemaLocation="v1.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="fromV2" type="v1:typeV1"/>
</xs:schema>
```

In the resulting XML, both namespaces have to be declared, e.g. like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v2:fromV2 xmlns:v2='my.com/V2.0.xsd'>
  <v1:fromV1 xmlns:v1='my.com/V1.0.xsd'/>
</v2:fromV2>
```

If you want only one namespace, you have to put the same uri in both schemas for targetNamespace and use include instead of import.